# What other angles apart from the right angle can be trisected?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, extension-field, angle, cubics, geometric-construction

Is there a way to characterise the set of all angles $0°<\phi<360°$ such that $\phi$ can be classically trisected? (That is, the trisection can only be done with a finite sequence of straight lines and circles.)

Of course, it is well-known that $90°$ can be trisected. (In fact, this question arose after I had shown my students a trisection of the right angle.) Now some other angles are trivially trisectable (e.g., $180°,270°, 360°$), but apart from these are there more interesting angles? Since there are infinitely many of them the only way to systematically characterise the set of all trisectable angles is to use algebra. From the trigonometric identity $$\cos\phi=4\cos^3\frac\phi 3-3\cos\frac\phi 3,$$ we see that the problem is essentially cubic. So in other words is there some criterion on $\cos\phi$ that tells us whether the cubic in $\cos\frac\phi 3$ is reducible to a lower degree polynomial over the extension of $\mathrm Q$ by $\cos\phi$? Clearly, it cannot simply be about the rationality or otherwise of $\cos\phi,$ since it is well-known, for example, that $60°$ cannot be trisected.

So is there a way to tell exactly which angles can be trisected? Or rather *is there a provably complete list of all trisectable angles* somewhere?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a complete criterion, which is why I'm not putting it in an answer: constructible angles are trisectable if and only if their trisection is constructible. For angles which are rational multiples of $2\pi$, this can be reduced to the question wether certain regular polygons are constructible, the answer to which is known: the regular $n$-gon is constructible iff $n$ is a product of a power of $2$ and distinct Fermat primes.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks. However, I am interested in any given angle, not just constructible ones. A question that has occurred to me is this: Can we even prove that the list I'm looking for is *finite*?

Comment: @Allawonder: *"Can we even prove that the list I'm looking for is finite?"* The list certainly isn't finite, since tripling any constructible angle yields a trisectable one. Regarding trisectable-but-not-constructible angles (eg, $3\pi/7$, as discussed in Cut-the-Knot's ["There are trisectable angles that are not constructible." entry](https://cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/trisect.shtml)), this [Dr. Math letter](https://nctm.org/tmf/library/drmath/view/77687.html) begins "I know a small but infinite subset of angles are trisectable", which suggests that research on the topic exists somewhere.

Comment: If $n\phi=2\pi+\phi/3$ ($n$ a natural number) then $\phi$ is certainly trisectable, so here you have an infinite family, with "most" of the members non-constructible.

Comment: @Blue Oh, of course, the list is infinite. That renders my question almost moot. Except there is a way to explicitly characterise them all.

Comment: @user8268 Thanks, but could you explain how you obtained these, and why they are *certainly* trisectable?

Comment: @Allawonder you simply start putting copies of the angle $\phi$ next to each other, until you get an overlap, and that overlap is $\phi/3$

Comment: @user8268 Oh, of course, when one thinks of it as $n\phi-2π =\phi/3.$